# How do I boot Windows 7 in a Virtual HD on a Mac?

Tags: windows-7, virtual-machine

I've got a Mac running Snow Leopard 10.6.8, and I need Windows 7 on it for work. I was going to dual boot using Boot Camp, but I'd rather use a Virtual HD (the program I d/led for it was VirtualBox). HOWEVER I only have a d/led version of Windows 7 burned onto a disk (a DVD burned at 4x) and VirtualBox refuses to recognize it as a bootable device.
Anything I can do about this? Is it an issue with the Windows I d/led or is it the media type?

Comment: There is a question that has a link to a Windows 7 Service Pack 1 ISO on this very website I would use that.  Clearly you need to burn another copy of the iso.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is to run my Boot Camp partition AS a VM. You can do this with VMware Fusion. It costs $50. I think it's worth it. Use the trial version to test it, works great for me. Fusion will detect your Boot Camp environment and automatically add a VM for it.

Comment: Wow that's amazing! Thanks, I will try it. Just gotta get that Windows install to work somehow...

Comment: Yeah, it's pretty awesome. Note that your Windows install will need to be "reactivated" and that MAY fail. The fix is to call their phone "system" and get it reactivated. Apparently when you boot natively again, it'll complain in there again, but after going back and forth a few times activating, it should stop complaining and work 100%. I haven't booted Windows natively for a long time though as VMware's just so awesome.